# IntelliJ (using gradle): Can't find Kotlin plugin even though it's installed

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

I'm trying to build my project using gradle but it seems that it can't find my kotlin plugin, even though I did add it using "install plugin from disk".

[image]

This is the error I'm getting:

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-release-1038.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-release-1038/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.0.0-release-1038.pom
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-release-1038/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.0.0-release-1038.jar

Can anyone help me with this? I'd really like to build my project.

Comment: When exactly you get following error? When execute build with gradle?

Comment: @IRus I get the error when I run any of the gradle tasks

Comment: Can you update Kotlin to Release version?

Comment: @IRus This is not an option, I need to work with this specific Kotlin version for this project.

Comment: Okay, it's not required, check my answer.

Comment: The plugin and gradle version are not connected, your question is misleading in itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can guess that you doesn't have repository in **build.gradle**, so please compare your build file with following, and then make "Gradle Refresh" in Idea.

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '<version to use>'
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // or better:
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin"

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  // or better:
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Pay more attention to **buildscript** part of config: **repositories** here is necessary!

I got config from [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#configuring-dependencies), with my little refinements.

Comment: If this doesn't help, i can take a look at your project if you will publish him on github.

Comment: I changed release-1038 to beta-1038 in version to use and it worked, I tried it because of your answer so thanks :)

Comment: Adding `mavenCentral()` did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, as I try to switch my build files to Kotlin.

Or, rather, as I try to convert them from Kotlin that seems to cause my tools to have occasional nervous breakdowns to the sort of Kotlin that does not.  I'm good at a lot of thing, but I'll take a nice, trustworthy GNU Make of gradle any day and twice on sundays, and gradle seems to feel the same way about me.

But it seemed to be working out well.  I read this article, and all the red and pink and yellow was disappearing out of my build files, and then,a ll of a sudden the damned thing decided that it had never heard of the Android Plugin, and wouldn't put any faith in that sort of nonsense, even if it had.

Actually, first it forgot what a classpath was.  Started telling me it had never heard the word,and didnt' appreciate that sort of language, anyway.

I know I heard something about not using the plugin *block*, but I don't know where.